# Ayuda con direccionamiento dentro de un Frame en HTML

Tags: html

Resulta que tengo un Frameset con varios Frames y dentro de un frame donde tengo una barra de navegación tengo ubicado los href....

Mi pregunta ¿Cómo hago para direccionar toda la pagina hacia la ubicación del href y no solo el frame del navbar?

Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, en la parte superior tengo el navbar, si oprimo 'INICIAR SESIÓN'  pasa esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se dirije al documento login.php pero solo en el Frame donde estaba el boton direccionador, ¿cómo haria para que toda mi pagina se dirija hacia login.php?

Comment: Un frame te abre una pagina dentro de tu pagina, entonces todas las acciones que tenga esa pagina, afectara al frame donde este. Quizas usando javascript y añadiendo callbacks podrías hacer lo que quieres, pero.. por qué usas frames para hacer el menu el resto del contenido, en lugar de darle un estilo a la pagina con CSS?

Comment: Eso era lo que tenia pensado hacer ahora, lo que pasa es que apenas ayer me di cuenta de los frameset XD, en la universidad ni me lo mencionaron, y pues estuve probando algunas cosas y me surgio esta duda, pero si no hay de otra entonces lo tendre que hacer con estilos CSS.